# How to refresh object in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-security

I have User class in my project. This class has field notes. It looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Proxy(lazy = false)
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Note> notes;
...
}
```

This class is used for Spring Security authentification like this:

```
public class AuthUser extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User {
    private User user;

    public AuthUser(String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
    }

    public AuthUser(User user, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        this(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.isActive(), true, true, true, authorities);
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

There is option for user to add new note. After saving new note using **session.save(note)** I'm trying to receive a list of user's note through **((AuthUser) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUser().getNotes()** but there is only old notes in this set. New list is not included. 
So as I understand user or list should be refreshed. What is the proper way to do this?
Or maybe it's better to just call user.getNotes().add(note) before or after saving?

Comment: not an expert in hibernate, but try to add   @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE}) after @OneToMany then call user.getNotes().add(note).

Answer (score 0):

Database ralatioships are unidirectional. It means foreign key is only in one table in relationship.
In contrast object relationships are bidirectional. It means you have reference on both sides (objects).

So there exists some class Note in your example, which contains reference to User. Only one side can manage the relationship. This side is called owning side. The other side is called inverse side. So if you save owning side (Note in your example) it will affect User in database.